# Usage of " on and In"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

She is **in a** depression
-->She is **on a** depression

She is **on a** diet
---> She is **in a** diet

she is **on a** vacation
--->she is **in a** vacation

He went there **on** business
--->He went there **in** business

Now Question is, is it ok if I replace **on** with **in**.

Comment: These are idioms. You simply say *to be/go on a diet* and not in. So no, you can't replace the preposition in these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace *on* with *in*, or vice versa regarding the first sentence.

These are all idiomatic uses, and you will sound like a non-native speaker if you don't stick to the uses you have marked with an arrow. (Yes, you basically have to memorize them.)

*In* can mean *contained within* or, sometimes *inside*, so the use of *in* with *depression* is partially explainable: depression is like a deep pit or hole that people fall into or are in, inside of.

As for *on*, we often use it in these types of expressions: on vacation, on business, on a business trip, on a journey, on a trek, on a walk, on a date; and with more the metaphorical: on a roll, on a streak.